# .htaccess rewrite for https and hidden subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite http://www.example.com and http://example.com to 
https://www.example.com.
An additional complexity is that these URLs are not pointing to the index file, but to the /folder. i.e. https://www.example.com really points to /var/www/html/folder, without showing https://www.example.com/folder in the URL bar.

I had previously managed to attain the second part with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

and I know that the first part can be attained with something like this:

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

but somehow I just can't get both of them to work together because I'm not familiar with htaccess. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single rule to add `www` and `http -> https` redirection and then have your rewrite rule for folder forward:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!folder/)(.*)$ folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I get this error: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Try my updated rules in a new browser or in command line `curl`

Comment: same outcome. I tried on firefox, chrome, safari and had cleared all history, cookies etc.

Comment: ok, test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get there.

Comment: ok i see more on Firefox's tool. it says request URL: https://www.example.com, remote address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 status code: 301 and then a whole series of the same

Comment: That means your web server is not recognizing `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` condition. What is your Apache version? Are you behind some proxy?

Comment: v2.2.34, there is an AWS load balancer, is that why? can i use %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161750/discussion-between-phantomhive-and-anubhava).

Comment: Try replacing `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` with `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80`